# how to fix 'Android resource compilation failed Output: values_values.arsc.flat: error: failed to open. '

Tags: java, android

Android resource compilation failed
Output:  values_values.arsc.flat: error: failed to open.

Command: C:\Users\KAMAL.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows.jar\1004f9e02d2cf44b39e5208f3f298ce2\aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows\aapt2.exe compile --legacy \
        -o \
        D:\AndroidRoomDbTutorial\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug \
        D:\AndroidRoomDbTutorial\app\build\intermediates\incremental\mergeDebugResources\merged.dir\values\values.xml
Daemon:  AAPT2 aapt2-3.2.1-4818971-windows Daemon #2

It is room database application .

Comment: Hello @RogerK have you tried to Clean and Rebuild project

Comment: Indent your code properly and show us the code where the error originates from.

Comment: Yes I did.@nilesh-panchal. Even I clear all the caches from 'C:User/AndroidStudio' drive.

Comment: @TaseerAhmad It is having 10 in number of .java file Coding. Then this question will become so long. Do you really need code , though compiler doesn't show error on any line of coding ?

Comment: I was expecting the compiler to direct to the point of error origin but in your case it not working. Can you open your values.xml file and look for any errors? I had kind of same error and I was able to fix it by modifying my value.xml file.

Answer (score 6):

I had this, turned out aapt was being blocked by antivirus.
Found answer here:
https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/unable-to-build-error-values-values-arsc-flat-error-failed-to-open/128575

Comment: Please [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) , and be sure with your [answer link](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)
 While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.
 [how to answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Now Android Studio will be giving you error for explicit values and if those values are coming from some library you are using then you can't make a change in the intermediate file so instead change here and while merging your code Android studio takes care of it.

```
<resources>
<item name="faqID" type="id">faq</item>
```

Changed it to:

```
<resources>
<item name="faqID" type="id"/>
```

Please refer this link 
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources#Id

You can also try as follows

If problem still exists please try as follows

- File | Invalidate Caches / Restart
- Deleting .idea folder
- Running gradlew clean
- Re-import the project

Comment: pardon, I couldn't get your solution and still with the same error."Android resource compilation failed
values-pt_values-pt.arsc.flat: error: failed to open."